# Formula of a circle in 3D plane to equirectangular 2D plane

Tags: geometry, transformation, projection

I have a plane $P$ that intersects a sphere $S$ with a radius $R$. The result of this intersection is a circle $C$ with the distance between its center and the sphere's center is $s$. In my case is always $R \geqslant s$ so I get a circle or a point-circle as a result of this intersection.

**Edit**
\begin{align*}
P: && ux + vy + wz + d =0\\
S: && x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2
\end{align*}
The formula of $C$ is of the form:
$$Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F =0.$$

What is the formula to represent (equirectangular project) $C$ on a 2D plane ($xOy$ plane)? I would have the circle $C$ plotted so on a 2D plane (it would like look the day-night terminator as in map below:

[image]

Globally it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Your formula for $C$ looks like a sphere to me.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I edited it

Comment: My goal is to represent a circle (not necesserily a great-circle) around a sphere (e.g. the globe) on a 2d plane (e.g. cylindrical equirectangular projection)

Comment: The you need to put all points from the circle through your projection.